# Ubuntu 20.04 very slow response or freeze at login after setting Prime Synchronization for Nvidia optimus laptop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, 20.04

So I have just done a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop (Intel i7 7700HQ + NVIDIA 1050Ti), I noticed that when enabling the NVIDIA driver (version 440.62) the laptop screen suffers from screen tearing, and I tried to enable Prime Synchronization by the [following method](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365449):

1. Create a new file `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf`;
2. Input `options nvidia_drm modeset=1` to the file;
3. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`
4. Reboot.

After rebooting the GUI had very slow response at login screen, sometimes I had to wait several minutes after input the password for my desktop to show up, sometimes the desktop never appeared. Even if the desktop appeared, it may still freeze after a random time. Reverting the previous steps can solve the problem but screen tearing re-appeared.

I hope to know what is the cause of this problem? Did I enable Prime Synchronization correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here. It appears that the problem is caused by an [old bug in gdm3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1716857) when Prime Synchronization is enabled. I found two potential solutions (or workarounds) from the discussions of the bug:

1. Use `lightdm` instead of `gdm3`. To do this, run the command `sudo apt install lightdm`, then choose `lightdm` as the default display manager when the terminal prompts you to do so. However, using `lightdm` will disable screen locking, and has a annoying bug that the mouse will change color at the desktop. Therefore, I use the second solution.
2. Continue to use `gdm3` as the display manager, but add `needs_root_rights=yes` to `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`, then reboot the machine.

I experienced no further problems when using the second solution. However, I am not sure about the potential security consequences of giving root access to Xwrapper. Many some experts on X11 or X server can comment on this.

Comment: I had this annoying problem for more than 6 months and the second solution worked for me like a charm!

Comment: didn't fix it for me. GTX 1050 TI on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use your Nvidia card regularly which was the case for me I just disabled my nouveau drivers which not only resulted in a smoother system but also solved my screen tearing.

For disabling my nouveau drivers I used this https://moduate.com/blog/disabling-nouveau-drivers-in-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: This is related to the proprietary driver, not noveau.