# Ubuntu 20.04 Freeze Quadro P600 Mobile

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I have recently switched to using Ubuntu on my laptop. The laptop, a HP Zbook 15vG5, has a Quadro P600 GPU, Intel I7 8750h and 32GB of RAM.
When I use my old GTX1060 via Thunderbolt it is all working fine and without any problems. The systems run stable and the performance is also right where you would expect it.

However if I try to use the laptop without the external GPU I get crashes approximately once every 1-3h. The screen freezes, however audio continues to run for a while until it also stops. I have tried now 3 different drivers, NVIDIA-455, NVIDIA-450  and NVIDIA-390. Noveau is not an option since I need CUDA support for some applications. The problem exists with all drivers.
Also the problem is independent of using external monitors via HDMI, Display port or the internal one.

Furthermore using the "on-Demand" PRIME profile causes the UI to respond very slowly. Each action takes over one second to complete.
I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230633/ubuntu-20-04-very-slow-response-or-freeze-at-login-after-setting-prime-synchroni) as a possible solution however running the wrapper with root privileges does not sound like a good idea to me. It fixed the slowness however it did not fix the crashes so I disabled it again.

What I found in the system log after the latest freeze is the following:

```
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999272] NVRM: GPU at PCI:0000:01:00: GPU-2024c25d-275a-4807-15d8-f2ec16f19df3
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999273] NVRM: Xid (PCI:0000:01:00): 79, pid=2318, GPU has fallen off the bus.
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999275] NVRM: GPU 0000:01:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999289] NVRM: A GPU crash dump has been created. If possible, please run
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999289] NVRM: nvidia-bug-report.sh as root to collect this data before
Oct  6 12:18:11 unkown kernel: [61883.999289] NVRM: the NVIDIA kernel module is unloaded.
```

However I do not know how I can run the nvidia-bug-report.sh. I do not have a device that I could use to remote into this one and also I am new to Linux so I am a bit lost.
Also all that I can find about that behavior is that there is a problem during the wake up however that is not the case for me. It happens while working on the laptop.

If you need any information please feel free to ask and I will do my best to provide it.

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that also the CPU fan ramps up to maximum once it starts to freeze.

Edit 2: In order to test if the GPU was damaged (I did not expect that since it was running fine with Windows a few days ago) I ran games and stresstests on the GPU. It was not a problem at all for the 30min I kept it running. I will keep the stresstest running for some time and update if  it also crashes during that time.